# Inserting specific number of rows in Excel

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2013, spreadsheet

I, for the life of me, can not figure out why M$ has not provided this feature. If I want to insert 597, for the sake of argument lets say blank, new rows, all available information tells me to either

1. Insert a row and hit F4 596 times
2. scroll down until I find 597 empty rows and copy then insert those

Is there an easier way to do this? I am flattening out inventory and this is a major PITA. Is there a logic behind this design choice?

Comment: Please describe the downvote

Comment: I'm not the down-voter, but maybe it's for the editorializing.

Comment: Please accept @Excellll answer it's the best and requires no additional installations or plugins

Answer (score 2):

You can select 597 rows below where you want them entered, right click the selection, and choose `Insert`. This will insert 597 new rows above your selection.

If you want an easy way of selecting 597 rows, I suggest using the Name Box, highlighted in the screenshot below.

[image]

For example, if you want to insert 597 rows beneath row 10, type `11:607` in the Name Box and press Enter. This will select those rows. Then, you can right-click the selection and choose `Insert`. Alternatively, you can insert the rows via keyboard by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> > <kbd>H</kbd> > <kbd>I</kbd> > <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, but selecting rows is not easy: Sometimes SHIFT acts wonky, with filters it is difficult to navigate to empty lines, go down past the bottom is slow, Page Down/Up is very sensitive...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say easy, but certainly a third option is a combination of the above.  Select 30 rows (say) with a key combination

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Page Down</kbd>

Then hit F4 20 times (inserts 600 I agree) but far easier than doing both the others.

Another option is vba, as below with the (1) being replaced by another column, so you enter the number in a cell and insert that many rows

```
ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert
```

Another alternative is to buy http://www.extendoffice.com/order/kutools-for-excel.html which has a neat option for this and many other useful purposes.

Comment: Probably easier and more cost effective to just hire another bookkeeper

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to use a plugin to give you added functionality. [ASAP Utilities](http://www.asap-utilities.com/asap-utilities-excel-tools-tip.php?tip=64&utilities=58&lang=en_us) offers this:

[image]

I was an active user of ASAP Utilities for a number of years and found it very useful for certain laborious tasks like this one. When I migrated to a new laptop several years ago I never reinstalled it (because my work required less repetitive stuff) so not sure how good the product is these days.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to Insert Multiple Rows in Excel

The solution below seems to be easiest way to insert a large number of rows.

For other solutions see the linked source article.

> **Method 4 –Programmatically inserting multiple rows in excel:**
>
> Although this method is a bit complex than the first three, but still
>   this can be used if you are more inclined towards the coding side.
>   Follow the below steps to use this method:
>
> - Navigate to the ‘View’ Tab on the top ribbon, click on the ‘Macros’ button.
> - Now type the name for the macro say “Insert_Lines” (without quotes) and hit the create button.
> - Next, a VBA editor will be opened, simply paste the below macro code after the first line.
>
> ```
>     Dim CurrentSheet As Object
>     ' Loop through all selected sheets.
>     For Each CurrentSheet In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
>     ' Insert 5 rows at top of each sheet.
>     CurrentSheet.Range("A20:A69").EntireRow.Insert
>     Next CurrentSheet
> ```
>
> **Inserting Multiple Rows Macro**
>
> - Now comes the important thing, in the above macro the range is (“A20:A69”).  - The first parameter i.e. A20 tells the position from
>     where you wish to insert the rows and the second parameter .i.e. A69
>     is the number of rows to be inserted added with the start position and
>     subtracted by 1
> - If you want to insert 50 rows starting
>     from A20 then second parameter of range should be (50+20-1), so the
>     range will be (“A20:A69”))
> - After adding the code you can press the “F5” key and the code will insert the required rows.
> - This macro is referenced from the Microsoft article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291305

Source [How to Insert Multiple Rows in Excel](http://www.exceltrick.com/how_to/insert-multiple-rows-in-excel/)

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub insertRows()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Variant
    j = InputBox("How many rows would you like to insert?", "Insert Rows")
    If j = "" Then
        j = 1
    End If
    For i = 1 To j
        ActiveCell.Rows.EntireRow.Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next
End Sub
```

This will open an InputBox where you can specify the number of rows to insert. By default, it will insert 1 if nothing is entered (there is no other error-handling). It starts at the current row of the cell that is selected, and inserts rows on a loop until the specified number have been inserted.

Comment: Surrounding your code by some explanation would really improve the value of your answer.